# What does this loop mean: 'while(string[i])'

Tags: c, while-loop, c-strings

I have this line of code that I don't understand.

```
char string[100];

while(string[i])
{
  //statements 

  i++;
}
```

Comment: It invokes *undefined behavior* by accessing the array out of bounds

Comment: Are you sure the original code wasn't something like `while(string[i])`?

Comment: is it the best way to iterate a string?

Comment: Unless the index changes in the loop, it does not iterate at all.

Comment: I ve fixed the code it looked like I ve missed the I for iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking whether this would be the best way to iterate over a string. I would say no, pointer arithmetic is the way to go. If you are indexing, then you have to operate with two variables, instead of one.

```
const char *str = "Hello World";
while (*str != '\0') {
    ++str;
}
```

or

```
for (; *str != '\0'; ++str)
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
while (string[i])
{
  //statements 

  i++;
}
```

is strictly equivalent to this:

```
while (string[i] != 0)
{
  //statements 

  i++;
}
```

In C an expression if considered as false if its value is 0, and true if its value is different from zero.

You could also write this

```
if (Foo)
  ...
```

instead of :

```
if (Foo != 0)
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

### To iterate:

> We use the term iteration, we are usually talking about loops. For, while, and do...while loops in C are loops that will execute as long as a condition is true. Iteration is one of the reasons that computer programs exist in the first place.
> *From the page of [Recursion & Iteration in C](https://study.com/academy/lesson/recursion-iteration-in-c-programming-definition-occurrence.html#:%7E:text=In%20programming%2C%20iteration%20denotes%20the,is%20much%20higher%20in%20recursion.)*

You can loop through the array elements with the **for** loop.

```
string cars[4] = {"Volvo", "BMW", "Fiat", "Ferrari","Mazda"};
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  cout << cars[i] << "\n";
}
```

You can loop through the array elements also with the **while** loop.

```
int arr[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int i = 0;
do
{
    printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    i++;
} while (i < 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the statement `while (string[i])` , we are checking if the value of `string[i]` is equal to `\0` (ASCII is 0), or not. If `string[i]` is equal to some character, then it enters the loop. If `string[i] = \0` (end of the string),then it exits the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char string[100] = "Krishna";
    int i=0;
    while (string[i]) // same as while(string[i] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c",string[i]);
        i++; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is : `Krishna`

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't have a type for boolean values (true/false) that's separate from integers. In C, an integer is true if it's nonzero, and false if it's zero. So `while (string[i])` is a loop that runs while `string[i]` is nonzero, i.e. while the character at index `i` in `string` is nonzero.

It would be equivalent, and arguably clearer, to write `while (string[i] != 0)` or `while (string[i] != '\0')`. (Note that `0` and `'\0'` are both the *integer* zero, which is also the character with the value zero since C doesn't also doesn't have a separate type for characters and integers. This is not the character that is the digit 0, which would be `'0'`.)

Strings in C are represented are null-terminated: the end of the string is indicated by a character with the value 0. (As a consequence, C strings can't contain the character 0. It's possible to represent strings differently, but then they won't be strings in the sense meant by the standard library functions like `strlen`, `strcpy`, etc.)

Therefore `while (string[i])` loops until it reaches the end of the string. It's a very common idiom.